# респонс сервера в консоли (ангуляр)

Tags: angularjs, google-chrome

Добрый вечер. Такой вопрос. Как в хроме сделать так, чтоб когда с бекенда приходил json обьект или обьекты, можно было в консоли посмотреть какие у него свойства и поля. Видел у людей можно просто развернуть обьект, и там будут его поля итд. У меня только написано что пришел обьект, без конкретики. На бэкенде спринг, на фронтенде ангуляр. Заранее спасибо.
[image: консоль хрома]

```
userService.getUser().success(function (data) {
    console.log("User : " + data);
    $scope.user = data;
});
```

Comment: Похоже данные возвращаются как строка, а не как объект (тип данных). Вполне может быть, что спасет Content-type.

Comment: что вы имеете ввиду под "спасет Content-type"? Куда это нужно дописать или я что-то не так понимаю? По поводу того, что возвращается строка а не обьект, я же потом обращаюсь к конкретным полям этого обьекта на вьюшке, и все работает, значит это всё таки обьект.

Comment: Значит в консоль выводится как строка.

Comment: я добавил в вопрос с верху как выглядит контроллер, где на консоль выводится обьект. Подскажите пожалуйста как тогда поменять эту строку, чтоб выводился не строка а обьект.

    console.log("User : " + data);

Comment: понял в чем проблема. Если делать конкатенацию обьекта со строкой, то получается строка).

Answer (score 2):

В данном случае в консоль выводится строка

```
console.log("User : " + data);
```

Для вывода непосредственно объекта, можно плюс заменить `,`

```
console.log("User : ", data);
```